# Facebook Graph API: How to get all links from page in API v2.7?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, deprecated

In Facebook Graph API v2.3 it was possible to get all links belong to specified page using "links" edge:

```
GET v2.3 {page_id}/links
```

This request shows really all links (not only **published**, which are accessible by /feed request). Graph API Explorer still can execute this request.

But all new Facebook applications can use only Graph API v2.7, not older. FQL also was deprecated at 08.08.2016.

So, how can I get all links from page (not only published) by Graph API v2.7 from my application? Even dirty hacks are appreciated, thank you.

**Upd.:** Links posts are [promotable posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/page/feed). They did not showed by **/feed**, only by **/promotable_posts**, which is necessary endpoint for my needs. I've found also a necessary parameter for this endpoint which shows really all links posts: include_inline.
So, final request is:

```
GET v2.7 {page_id}/promotable_posts?include_inline=true
```

Answer (score 0):

> GET /v2.4/{id}/links and GET /v2.4/{id}/statuses will no longer be available beginning in v2.4. As an alternative, we suggest using GET /v2.4/{id}/feed.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

So you will have to use the `feed` endpoint and filter out links on your own.

Comment: Not all links are accessible via /feed, read the question carefully please.

Comment: Found an answer (see an update in post for details): `GET v2.7 {page_id}/promotable_posts?include_inline=true`

Comment: i did read the question carefully, do you mean "the feed endpoint does not include unpublished ones"?

Comment: either way, the official replacement is the feed endpoint, as you can read in the changelog. maybe they did not realize that people may want to get unpublished ones too.